# Структура сайта: правильные названия

Tags: php, html

Вопрос, на который не могу ответить, часто когда делаю новый сайт, вступаю в ступор, когда надо сделать вывод списка товаров и его детальную страницу: как правильнее назвать файл детальной страницы detail.php или же deteil.php?

Answer (score 1):

Детали - details, гласит переводчик google. Значит, detail.

Comment: Согласен, в ваших словах есть логика, но именно это меня и смущает, приведу пример - наберите в яндексе слова битрикс и detail.php и выходит очень много примеров кода, даже из ихней документации - вот это меня и пугает, то ли это глобальный заговор, то ли опечатка и все стали ее повторять.

Comment: На эти случаи действительно есть словарь. То, что кто-то написал deteil показывает только его невежество. Как и "ихней", впрочем. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

detail.php однозначно.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вообще `product.php` назвать, что будет более точно отражать сущность.

Comment: продукт непонятно в каком формате - то ли полный то ли краткий

Comment: Или page.php

Comment: Полное или краткое описание продукта (товара) находится на открытой странице, должно определяться не названием, а, например, правами или пользовательскими настройками.
Мне кажется, пользователь сам может "развернуть" информацию о товаре на странице `product.php`. А вот `detail.php` в контексте сайта (товары) вообще ни на что не наводит.

Answer (score 0):

`product_card, pcard, prod_card, detail, prod_detail`, ... дальше продолжать? =)